# Why is Value String not a stable identifier even when defined as a val

Tags: scala, spray, spray-json

```
object HydraTable extends Enumeration {
  val UserTable, MpesaTable, ChequeTable, PaypalTable = Value
}

matchTable.tableType match {

  case HydraTable.UserTable.toString =>
    // do somet
  case HydraTable.MpesaTable.toString => 
    // do somet
    // returns error below
```

This returns an error on case -> 
HydraQueueWorker.scala:58: stable identifier required, but HydraTable.MpesaTable.toString found.

Are the values not stable identifiers?

Comment: By convention, stable identifier must start with an uppercase, or by backquoted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `toString` is a method and its invocation can yield a different value each time : you can easily create a case class and override the `toString` to return the string value of a random integer

If you look at the `toString` definition you see it's a method  (and a non final one)

```
@SerialVersionUID(8476000850333817230L)
abstract class Enumeration (initial: Int) extends Serializable {
  thisenum =>

 def this() = this(0)

  /* Note that `readResolve` cannot be private, since otherwise
     the JVM does not invoke it when deserializing subclasses. */
  protected def readResolve(): AnyRef = thisenum.getClass.getField(MODULE_INSTANCE_NAME).get(null)

  /** The name of this enumeration.
   */
  override def toString =
    ((getClass.getName stripSuffix MODULE_SUFFIX_STRING split '.').last split
       Regex.quote(NAME_JOIN_STRING)).last
```

So you can create your enumeration, override it and return a random value.

Comment: you mean when I call a `.toString` on an element on the enum I can get a random Value each time? @Edmondo1984

Comment: Updated answer, apologies about code formatting I am using the mobile app :)

Answer (score 1):

Your path can't have a `var` or a `def` anywhere in it. This applies to the current type that the compiler infers for items in the path.

For example:

```
object Obj0 {
   val field0 = "a"

   override val toString = "b"
}

object Obj1 {
   def field1 = Obj0
}

object Obj2 {
   val field2 = Obj0

   val field3 = Obj1

   val field4: Any = Obj0

   def thing = "c" match {
     case field2.field0 => "this is okay"
     case field3.field1.field0 => "" // compile error
     case field2.toString => "also okay"
     case field4.toString => "" // compile error
   }
}
```

Comment: I don't however have a def or var anywhere there

Comment: Unless you override `toString` to be a `val` such as in `Obj0`, `toString` is a `def`.

Comment: Ah, I get it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can match on an enum like this

```
matchTable match {
  case HydraTable.PaypalTable => ???
}
```

If you want to use the String value of the enum you could create an extractor

```
object TableNameExctractor {
  def unapply(table: HydraTable.Value): Option[String] = Some(table.toString)
}
```

Your match would look like this

```
matchTable match {
  case TableNameExctractor(tableName) => ???
}
```

Comment: `case TableNameExtractor(HydraTable.MpesaTable)` => for instance returns  scrutinee is incompatible with pattern type; I also get a warning, It's also a fruitless match - a Value and String.

Comment: I the extractor example `tableName` is a val containing the name of the matchTable. So you could add an if in the match `case TableNameExtractor(tableName) if tableName == "MpesaTable" => ???`. Although matching on the enum value would be more clear.